# Project Euler #22 C++

Tags: c++

I am working through the project euler problems in C++ and am stuck with my code on problem 22.  Below is my cpp and the answer I am getting is 871202730, or 4448 too high.  I've output the sorted list and checked that some of the names scores are calculated correctly and that I have the correct number of names.  Hopefully it's something simple and I just need some fresh eyes to look it over.  [Link to the question.](http://projecteuler.net/problem=22)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int sum = 0;
    vector<string> names;
    char name[50], junk[5];
    string str;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("docs/names.txt");

    while(!inFile.eof()) {
        inFile.getline(junk, 50, '/"');
        inFile.getline(name, 50, '/"');
        stringstream sstr;
        sstr << name;
        sstr >> str;
        names.push_back(str);
    }

    sort(names.begin(), names.end());

    for(int i=0; i<names.size(); i++) {
        int namesum = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<names[i].size(); j++)
            namesum += (names[i][j] - 64);
        sum += (namesum*i);
    }

    cout << "Sum: " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using forward-slash in your character literals? It should be backward-slash if you want to escape the double-quote `"`. Which you don't need to escape in a character literal anyway.

Comment: Other than that, don't use e.g. `while (!eof)`, it doesn't really work the way you expect it to. Instead use `while (getline && getline)`.

Comment: Thank you, the forward slashes were a mistake and I just forgot to take them out.  Using the while( getline ) actually gave me the right answer so maybe the input file was just giving me some junk at the end??  

[SO courtesy Q] - Should I delete my question now?  Or can I mark it as no longer necessary?

Comment: The reason is that the EOF flag isn't set until an input operation tries to read beyond the end of the file. As for the question, I will add an answer that you can mark as accepted.

Comment: Just out of curiosity: the `sum+=(namesum*i)` shoudnt be `sum+=(namesum*(i+1))`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When reading a stream, the end-of-file flag isn't set until an input operation tries to read beyond the end of the file and fails. That's why you can't do like

```
while (!inFile.eof()) { ... }
```

If you do like above, the input operations will fail and don't update the input strings properly.

Instead you should do like this:

```
while(inFile.getline(junk, 50, '"') && inFile.getline(name, 50, '"')) { ... }
```